# How to install Python Extension in VScode for all users of a machine

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying install the Python Extension for VSCode for all users of a machine, but it is getting installed for only the current user. Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: What system are you using? Could you explain the meaning of "for all users" In detail?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and it is a VDI, I want to add the extension to all the users who will be use this VDI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved after saving the path "C:\Users<userProfile>.vscode\extensions"  using the our Profile management tool. the data related to the extensions is stored in above mentioned path. so after saving the path users were able to add the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the root directory for extensions when launching code with the [`code --extensions-dir` command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery). You could also try and script the installation of the extension from a downloaded VSIX at start-up or something. Otherwise I think extension management is designed to be a personal thing and not system controlled (especially with VS Code itself support relocatable installs).

Comment: Hello Brett, Thanks for your response. yes the extensions management is a user based setting, so I was not able to install it on Machine level. But we managed to save the location "C:\Users\<userProfile>\.vscode\extensions"  at this path the data related to the extensions is stored.